# Edit button on GridView not updating with input box data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I know this is very basic, almost so basic it is difficult to find relevant examples.

I have a gridview table querying from database, and using VS17 I am trying to add an edit column. I have generated the following code using the designer layout but when I click the edit buttons, the row becomes editable but the update statement doesn't update the database. Once I click update, the page refreshes and the table disappears.

Where am I going wrong? Also, I am aware of the spelling errors my predecessor used in the column names.

Here's the cs file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CMSWebParts_Custom_Intranet_Data_inventorycountsheetcategorydatagridedit" CodeFile="~/CMSWebParts/Custom/Intranet/Data/inventorycountsheetcategorydatagridedit.ascx.cs" %>
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PartCatagoriesID" DataMember="DefaultView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategroyDescription" HeaderText="CategroyDescription" SortExpression="CategroyDescription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PartCatagoriesID" HeaderText="PartCatagoriesID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PartCatagoriesID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Form_IntranetSharpTransit_PartCategories] WHERE [PartCatagoriesID] = ?" EnableViewState="False" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Form_IntranetSharpTransit_PartCategories] ([CategoryName], [CategroyDescription], [PartCatagoriesID]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryName], [CategroyDescription], [PartCatagoriesID] FROM [Form_IntranetSharpTransit_PartCategories]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Form_IntranetSharpTransit_PartCategories] SET [CategoryName] = ?, [CategroyDescription] = ? WHERE [PartCatagoriesID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PartCatagoriesID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategroyDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PartCatagoriesID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategroyDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PartCatagoriesID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's the ascx file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using CMS.PortalControls;
using CMS.GlobalHelper;
using CMS.TreeEngine;
using CMS.CMSHelper;
using CMS.ExtendedControls;

public partial class CMSWebParts_Custom_Intranet_Data_inventorycountsheetcategorydatagridedit: CMSAbstractWebPart
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables or disables resolving of inline controls.
    /// </summary>
    public bool ResolveDynamicControls
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(this.GetValue("ResolveDynamicControls"), true);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("ResolveDynamicControls", value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Enables or disables HTML encoding of text.
    /// </summary>
    public bool EncodeText
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(this.GetValue("EncodeText"), false);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue("EncodeText", value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Content loaded event handler.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnContentLoaded()
    {
        base.OnContentLoaded();
        SetupControl();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the control properties.
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetupControl()
    {
        if (this.StopProcessing)
        {
            // Do not process
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Reloads the control data.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ReloadData()
    {
        base.ReloadData();

        SetupControl();
    }



}
```

Very basic, I know, but this isn't my forte and I can't seem to find an applicable example or bit of documentation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the following attributes to your grid view and then implement them in your code behind. If you're using VS17 it'll help you do this tremendously. Inside your grid view start with typing `OnRowEditing`, `OnRowUpdating`. That should get you started. You'll probably want to implement the `OnRowCancelingEdit` method too.

Comment: I've used this advice to create a GridView1_RowEditing method. Basically, this method will somehow store whats in the form and the OnRowUpdating method will, what? Execute a query of some kind to update?

Comment: You might want to consider using data tables and a data adapter. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll read up on data tables during lunch and have a look!

Comment: Not a problem. If that works for you, it'd be greatly appreciated if it's accepted as the answer. But not unless it actually helped.

Comment: It ended up being the OnRowUpdating method. I suspect I could have done it with a data table but I ended up storing the variables and using a stored procedure! Probably not the best method but your advice got me going. Thanks again :)